# C# program skips everything inside Main()

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to run a console-app-simulation of an atm machine.
The program is inside a class with a constructor that links the set/get paths to the console user input. I have no errors in vscode, but when I got to fn -> f5 to debug, the console prints the default "end of application" verbiage. Nothing from my Main() function is executed.
I tested the debugger by adding var x= 0 to see if I could add a breakpoint and THAT works, but it still skips everything afterward.
I am new to C# so I am sure it's probably something SO SIMPLE that I can't even google my way out of it. I am using .NET6.0 `enter code here`

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var x = 0;
        //give user a set of options
        void printOptions()

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose from one of the following options...");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Deposit");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Withdraw");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Show Balance");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");
            // x = 1;
        }
```

any ideas or direction as to why my program is ignoring its children would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you do not call the local method `printOptions`. Just add `printOptions();` as the last line of the code you have shown in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `void printOptions()`, what exactly do you expect that to do? Do you understand what a *method* is? Do you understand what it means to *call* a method? "I tested the debugger by adding var x= 0 to see if I could add a breakpoint and THAT works, but it still skips everything afterward" Do you see how the working code is different from the non-working code? In particular, in terms of how it's indented - whether it's inside or outside of `printOptions`? Did you try putting e.g. a `Console.WriteLine` outside of `printOptions`?

Answer (score 3):

all you need to do is to call the function you are defining :

```
    // This is where you call the function you defined.
    printOptions();

    // This is your function definition
    void printOptions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose from one of the following options...");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Deposit");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Withdraw");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Show Balance");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");
        // x = 1;
    }
```